# Does REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES permission lead to "Google Play Protect warning"?

Tags: android, permissions, installation

I have built 5 app with different sign key and they are not on googleplay market.
And user downloads and installs my apps from little banner ad click ,which I put in my apps(Internal downloader and then install app AND NOT market link!).
I use "REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" to get install permission and android targetsdk is 28 .Is this permission dangerous to use? And would "googleplay protect" detects it as a dangerous app and show warning protection dialog when user installs it?
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at my answer I posted below:

[Why HMS PushKit needs android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65977403/why-hms-pushkit-needs-android-permission-request-install-packages/65977463#65977463)

I've given allot of detail into why not to use this permission, and how it poses a security risk for google, (so much to the point that they will reject the app, if any dependency has this permission on its manifest).